# Does first isomorphism theorem hold in the category of normed linear spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory

Consider the category of normed linear spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ with bounded linear maps as morphisms. If $M\subset X$ is a subspace, then the quotient space $X/M$ has a map $\|x+M\|: = \inf_{y\in M}\|x-y\|_X$, which is a norm iff $M$ is closed in $X$ under the topology induced by the norm of $X$.

Let $f:L\to M$ be bounded linear map between two normed linear spaces, it is easy to check that $\ker f$ is indeed closed, thus $L/\ker f$ is a normed linear space itself. Is it true that
$$L/\ker f\cong f(L)$$
i.e. there exist invertible bounded linear map whose inverse is also bounded?

I checked that the canonical vector space isomorphism $L/\ker f \to f(L)$ is indeed bounded, but I have trouble showing that the inverse is bounded, or equivalently, continuous. In other words, I want to show that 
$$\forall \epsilon>0. \exists \delta>0. \|f(l)-f(m)\|<\delta \Longrightarrow \|(l+\ker f)-(m+\ker f)\|<\epsilon$$
Is it true or is there a counterexample? If the statement is true, then what about the stronger statement: If $f:L\to M$ is an ismorphism of linear spaces that is bounded, then $f^{-1}$ is also bounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not hold in general.

Consider an operator on $l^2$ defined by

$$T:(x_n)_{n < \omega} \mapsto (\frac{x_n}{n})_{n < \omega} \;. $$

This is a bouded linear operator (of the norm $1$) and it is injective, i.e. $\text{Ker } T=0$. So the quotient space is isomorphis to $l^2$ (even as Banach spaces, i. e. the norm remains the same). However, the inverse from the image of $T$
$$(x_n)_{n < \omega} \mapsto (nx_n)_{n < \omega}$$

is clearly not bounded.

Also note that even though this is actually a counterexample to the "stronger statement" you mention, the "stronger statement" itself is actually just a special case of the original question (when considering the isomorphism theorem for injective operators). Therefore it works as a counterexample for both claims.

**EDIT:** As Martin Brandenburg pointed out, the claim is true assuming both the space $L$ (domain of $f$) and the image of $f$ are Banach spaces.

Comment: Are you sure that the inverse $\mathrm{im}(T) \to l^2$ is not bounded? Notice that $\mathrm{im}(T) \neq l^2$.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg: I am sure that the inverse is not bounded, since the "canonical vectors" $e^k,  (e^k)_n=\delta_{kn}$ are of the norm 1 and are all in the image (and the inverse image of $e_k$ has norm $k$). However, this probably simply means that the image is not Banach space, i.e. is not complete - which is not a problem, since the question is about the category of normed linear spaces in general.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes for Banach spaces, using the [Open mapping Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Schauder_theorem)

Comment: Let $f:L\to M$ be a bounded linear map between two Banach spaces $L$ and $M$, there is no reason why $f(L)$ must be closed, thus $f(L)$ need not be Banach. The object $f(L)$ might not be in the category to begin with.

Comment: @mezhang: It is actually irrelevant whether the codomain $M$ is Banach; it is needed that the image $f(L)$ is a Banach space (which is probably what Martin Brandenburg meant by the statement).

Comment: @PavelC We need to use that $L/\ker f$ is a Banach space to use open mapping theorem right? How to prove it?

Comment: It is a general fact that the quotient of a Banach space modulo a closed subspace is again a Banach space.